# Can I have Comments open to specific users only?

Tags: comments

Like for example, I have 5 users I want to give permission to comment, but no one else.

But everyone needs to be able to read them. (Publicly viewable)

Like a blog about a show with 5 actors and I only want them to be able to comment on this specific page. This is for a custom page template.

I think I could use this action hook, but I can't find any examples by searching.

```
768  *
769  * @param int $post_id An optional post ID to check instead of the current post.
770  * @return bool True if the comments are open
771  */
772 function comments_open( $post_id = null ) {
773 
774      $_post = get_post($post_id);
775 
776      $open = ( 'open' == $_post->comment_status );
777      return apply_filters( 'comments_open', $open, $post_id );
```

Would it be something as simple as this pseudo code?

```
if my_user_can_post_comments = true {
     add_filter('comments_open', true, $ID);
} else {
     add_filter('comments_open', false, $ID);
}
```

Comment: The main trouble I was having was with the action hook and actually being able to set it's enabled or disabled status per condition. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for a user role. This should work when you put the code into the template above the call to `comments.php`:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'actor' ) ) // or use 'publish_posts'
    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_true' );

That worked! Thanks, it was getting it to return true properly that wasn't working for me. I'm slowly getting better with Callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the ID of the users who are allowed to comment I don't see why you can't do something like this.

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); //get data of logged in user
 $user_ID = $current_user->ID; //current users id
 $allowed_users = array(3,6,9,10,33); //array of users who are allowed to comment

 if(in_array($user_ID, $allowed_users)) {
       add_filter('comments_open', true, $ID);
 } else {
        add_filter('comments_open', false, $ID);
 }
```

To be honest, not sure if the filter code itself will work. If you provide more details maybe I can tell you for sure. However, the logic is good and hopefully puts you on the right track. It basically just uses PHP's [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and check an arrayed of allowed ID's against the logged in users id.

You may also be able to wrap [comment_form();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

Comment: Yea, the issue isn't checking if the user has permission, it's disabling the comment form.